# How to using variable when define not using initComponent ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have a question when defining 1 panel.

Ex1:

```
Ext.define('AppTest.view.AppMain', {
extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
xFile: "File",
    // Init
    initComponent: function () {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [ 
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    action: 'file',
                    text: this.xFile // Using variable here
                }
            ]
        });
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Ex2:

```
Ext.define('AppTest.view.AppMain', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    xFile: "File",
    items: [ 
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            action: 'file',
            text: this.xFile // Using variable at here
        }
    ]
});
```

When I run 2nd Example, only Example 1 create "File" is text of button, and Example 2 just creating button, but "File" is not text of button.

Please help me explain the difference between the two ways of `define`, and how to use Example 2 still using `this.xFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of **javascript closures**. In first example `this` keyword refers to the defined object. ( here is your class instance). In simple words, you should find the closest function wrapper (here initComponent).

But in your second example, `this`  refers to the `window` object which it has not `xFile` property. So it returns null. For test put the following line at the **top** of the second example and see the result :

```
this.xFile = 'hello!';
```

Finally I strongly recommend you to read in dept about `closures` and `prototypes` in javascript before coding complex scripts.